# Как начать пользоваться MVP + WinForms?

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, mvp

Пишу приложение с использованием БД - Firebird. Компьютеры у людей не очень мощные и WPF там тормозит. Поэтому необходимо на WinForms (прощай удобный MVVM). Узнал что для удобной работы люди используют MVP.

Есть какой-то вводный материал или статьи нормальные на эту тему, или может собственный опыт у кого есть? Ибо самостоятельное выяснение нормальных результатов не дало.

Comment: Я честно говоря первый раз слышу, что WPF медленнее WinForms.

Comment: @derkode Вы видать не запускали его на Windows XP а уж тем более на Pentium 4 или самых первых Core 2 Duo. Вообщем компах 7-10 летней давности

Comment: @adamshakhabov, а почему оно должно быть быстрее?

Comment: в winforms можно отделить UI от модели. т.к. в winforms есть привязки, включая иерархические. и UI не знает о модели, т.к. получает ссылку на object. пример привязок -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478616)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Немного ссылок:

[Вводная от Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter)

[Model-View-Presenter и сопутствующие паттерны](http://rsdn.ru/article/patterns/ModelViewPresenter.xml)

[Особенности реализации MVP для Windows Forms](http://habrahabr.ru/post/211899/) (тут, на мой взгляд, немного наворочено, но для ознакомления тоже подойдет)

---

Изложу также свой опыт.

Для каждого экрана должно быть три модуля: модель, представление и презентер.

- Модель отвечает за работу с данными (загрузка/сохранение). Она является своеобразным фасадом к некоторому источнику данных или к слою доступа к данным. Ее задача -- загружать и сохранять данные согласно задачам *конкретного экрана*.
- Представление отвечает за пользовательский интерфейс. Это, по сути, и есть ваш экран. Представление вызывает методы презентера (например, в обработчиках событий), а также предоставляет методы для отображения данных (они вызываются презентером).
- Презентер отвечает за взаимодействие между представлением (которое умеет только показывать данные и реагировать на действия пользователя) и моделью (которая знает только про данные). Как правило, это включает в себя логику представления данных, валидацию и другие вещи, тесно связанные с интерфейсом.

Направление ссылок получается следующим: представление <-> презентер -> модель. Важно запомнить, что эта тройка нужна *для каждого экрана*. Это не что-то единое для всего приложения. Иногда возможны исключения: в случае необходимости единого управления несколькими экранами может быть несколько представлений/моделей и всего один презентер.

Например, на экране есть кнопка "Загрузить заказы". В обработчике кнопки вызывается соответствующий метод презентера -- `LoadOrders()`. Внутри метода презентера идет обращение к модели, внутри модели непосредственно загружаются данные. После того, как презентер получил от модели данные, он может как-то преобразовать их для показа или выполнить над ними какую-то логику. После этого данные либо возвращаются из метода, либо -- что более канонично -- вызывается метод представления `SetOrders()`, внутри которого данные уже непосредственно загружаются в какой-либо контрол.

По коду получается следующая структура. Представление:

```
interface IOrdersView
{
    void SetOrders(Order[] orders);
}

class OrdersForm : Form, IOrdersView
{
    private OrdersPresenter presenter;

    public void OrdersForm()
    {
        ...
        // презентер можно создавать в конструкторе,
        // а можно иметь отдельный метод инициализации экрана,
        // который будет вызываться сразу после создания формы,
        // создавать презентер и вызывать у него метод загрузки данных
        presenter = new OrdersPresenter(this, new OrdersModel());
    }

    void btnLoadOrders_Click(...)
    {
        presenter.LoadOrders();
    }

    void IOrdersView.SetOrders(Order[] orders)
    {
        // загружаем данные в контрол
    }
}
```

Презентер:

```
class OrdersPresenter
{
    private readonly IOrdersView view;
    private readonly IOrdersModel model;

    OrdersPresenter(IOrdersView view, IOrdersModel model)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;
    }

    void LoadOrders()
    {
        var orders = model.LoadOrders();
        view.SetOrders(orders);
    }
}
```

Модель:

```
interface IOrdersModel
{
    Order[] LoadOrders();
}

class OrdersModel : IOrdersModel
{
    Order[] IOrdersModel.LoadOrders()
    {
        // тут логика по загрузке
    }
}
```

Интерфейсы в принципе опциональны, но удобны для тестирования и моков.

---

Вопросы из комментариев:

> А как мне допустим если в таблице (DataGridView) изменили запись,
>   записать эти изменения в базу. Сразу причем. То есть как только
>   закончили редактирование сразу в базу.

Отслеживаете событие изменения ячейки/строки, вызываете презентер, передав ему измененную запись, дальше презентер при необходимости валидирует и передает запись на сохранение модели. А модель уже обращается к слою доступа к данным (DAL'у).

> В интерфейсе IOrdersView объявлен метод SetOrders(), который принимает
>   значение типа Order[]. Но что это за тип? Где он описан?

В данном случае это какой-то пользовательский тип. Важное тут -- что `SetOrders()` принимает некоторые данные, которые готовы для отображения и которые представление (в данном случае форма) знает, как отображать. Это может быть и `DataTable`, и массив строк. Что угодно.

> Во View Вы создаете экземпляр класса OrdersPresenter и в качестве
>   параметра передаете экземпляр класса OrdersModel. Насколько это
>   укладывается в концепцию? Разве View и Model не должны быть развязаны
>   и ничего не знать друг о друге?

В идеале -- да, представление и модель должны быть развязаны и не должны ничего знать друг о друге. Создание экземпляра модели внутри представление является некоторым упрощением, и в целом втискивается в шаблон, поскольку представление не использует модель *явным образом*. Если же оставаться пуристом, то есть следующие варианты:

- Создавать модель внутри презентера. Главный недостаток -- плохая
  тестируемость презентера, поскольку невозможно подменить модель своей
  реализацией (а в тестах на презентер она всегда подменяется). Обойти
  это можно имея в презентере два конструктора -- один создает модель по умолчанию, второй -- принимает модель извне. Хотя и тут найдутся пуристы, утверждающие, что иметь специальные члены, которые используются только в тестах, плохо. Поэтому я иду по простому пути и всегда создаю модель в представлении.
- Передавать в представление уже созданный презентер. Т.о. модель будет
  инициализирована по крайней мере вне текущего представления. Однако
  по большому счету это ничего не дает, т.к. текущее представление
  будет открываться из другого представления, и теперь уже другому
  представлению нужно будет что-то знать о модели.

> Правильно я понял, что если у меня в программе 100 таблиц и мне нужно
>   100 форм для работы с ними, то для каждой формы я должен содать свой
>   интерфейс IOrdersModel и класс унаследованный от него, который может
>   быть уже не Orders, а Person, например и свой Presenter? Интерфейс
>   типа IOrdersView тоже для каждой формы создавать?

В общем случае да, для каждой `XXXForm` у вам должны быть `XXXView`, `XXXPresenter` и `XXXModel`. Однако если форм действительно много и они очень однотипные, то, возможно, достаточно будет обобщенных `IView<T>`, `Presenter<T>`, `IModel<T>`, где T -- конкретный тип редактируемой сущности.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34534/discussion-on-answer-by-andreycha----mvp-winforms).

Comment: ссылка на rsdn умерла

Comment: @PashaPash RSDN, похоже, целиком лежит, и rsdn.ru, и rsdn.org. Подождем.

Comment: Отличный ответ, спасибо. Хотел бы задать вопрос - например элементы управления могут быть выделены, и следовательно селекшен нужно где-то хранить, где необходимо хранить это состяние представления? в моей системе ценностей, этим должен заниматься презентер - а именно, управлять селекшеном, в случае его изменения вызывать методы у вьюх типа - `set_selected(false/true)`

Comment: @LmTinyToon да, все верно.

Answer (score 6):

> WPF там тормозит. Поэтому необходимо на WinForms (прощай удобный MVVM).

Прощаться с MVVM не обязательно если реализация моделей в WPF-приложении не зависит от контролов, то модели можно перенести в WinForms. Т.к. в WinForms есть своя реализация bindings, но она немного менее удобная чем в WPF.
Пример Model и View с bindings.
Модель отделена от View, т.к. модель остается прежней, если поменять View.

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    var m = new Model();
    View.Show(m);
}
class View {
  static public void Show(object model) {
     var f = new Form();
     var b = new RadioButton() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
     // привязываем RadioButton.Checked к значению bool SomeValue
     b.DataBindings.Add("Checked", model, "SomeValue");
     var t = new TextBox() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Top };
     // привязываем Text к свойству int Number. привязка как TwoWay в WPF.
     var tb = t.DataBindings.Add("Text", model, "Number", 
                 true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
     // это как IValueConverter в WPF
     tb.Format += (s, e) =>
         // транслируем данные из model.Number в TextBox.Text
         e.Value = e.Value + "!";
     tb.Parse += (s, e) => {
         // транслируем TextBox.Text в model.Number.
         var m = Regex.Match(e.Value.ToString(), "\\d+");
         e.Value = Convert.ChangeType(m.Success ? m.Value : "0", e.DesiredType);
         };
     f.ShowDialog();
  }
}
```

---

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public Model() {
        // таймер - для изменения свойств модели. они будут выводиться в View.
        var t = new Timer() { Interval = 500 };  
        t.Tick += (s, e) => {
            this.SomeValue = !this.SomeValue;
            this.Changed("SomeValue");
        };
        t.Start();
    }
    // событие необходимо для уведомлений о том, что изменились значения свойств 
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };
    private void Changed(string name) {
        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
    // свойства
    public bool SomeValue { get; set; }
    public int Number {
        get { return _Number; }
        set { 
            _Number = value;
            MessageBox.Show(value.ToString()); // тут это только для примера
            Changed("Number");
        }
    }
    int _Number = 123;
}
```

После открытия формы RadioButton переключается каждый полсекунды.
А если начать ввод значения в TextBox, то строка преобразуется в число и передается в Model.Number и откроется MessageBoх.

Как видно, Model и View отделены друг от друга. И достаточно просто заменить View, не меняя при этом Model.
Если Model определить в отдельной сборке, то ее можно использовать как в WinForms, так и в WPF приложениях.

Comment: другой пример привязки данных -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474645/196972)