# Где следует применять асинхронность при использовании паттерна MVP?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Правильно ли в Presenter использовать асинхронность? Или лучше реализовывать во View? Или не принципиально.

Answer (score 2):

В [описании](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter) сказано: Presenter — управляет Моделью и Представлением. Например извлекает данные из Модели и форматирует их для отображения в Представлении.

Представление - это UI, который, например, в .NET WinForms или WPF, реализуется в виде контролов -- они создаются в основном потоке приложения, и работать с контролами можно только из этого потока.
Но для извлечения данных из Модели можно и часто нужно использовать асинхронность, чтобы основной поток оставался свободным и UI не тормозил во время выборки данных.   Для этого Presenter создает отдельный поток, в котором обращается к Модели, далее  форматирует полученные данных, и передает данные в основной поток для вывода в Представление.

p.s.
Вместо MVP в .NET WPF используется [MVVM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-ViewModel), который также можно использовать и в WinForms -- пример на C# - [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474676/196972).