# Помогите разобраться с отделением бизнес-логики от формы

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, mvp

Я только начинаю осваивать C#. Сейчас пытаюсь разобраться в аспектах проектирования приложения для работы с базами данных. Практически каждый раз я слышу такую фразу "бизнес-логика должна существовать отдельно от формы". Но я не совсем понимаю как этого добиться при программировании WinForms?

Посоветуйте пожалуйста исчерпывающее руководство или литературу на этот счет.

**UPD:**

На данный момент удалось понять, что при использовании WinForms необходимо использовать паттерн MVP. И единственный пример использования MVP для WinForm, по которому удалось построить рабочее приложение, я смог найти вот в этом топике [Как начать пользоваться MVP + WinForms?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-mvp-winforms). Следую изложенной в нём информации у меня получилось следующее приложение.

Можете оценить, насколько у меня получилась правильная реализация применения паттерна MVP и отделения бизнес-логики от формы?

**View**

```
using System.Linq;

namespace EFCodeFirstMVP
{
    interface IView
    {
        void SetData(IQueryable<Goods> items);
    }
}

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace EFCodeFirstMVP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form, IView
    {
        private readonly GoodsPresenter presenter;

        public Form1()
        {
            presenter = new GoodsPresenter(this, new GoodsModel());
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void SetData(IQueryable<Goods> items)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = items.ToList();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            presenter.LoadData();
        }
    }
}
```

**Presenter**

```
namespace EFCodeFirstMVP
{
    class GoodsPresenter
    {
        private readonly IView view;
        private readonly IModel model;

        public GoodsPresenter(IView view, IModel model)
        {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        public void LoadData()
        {
            var data = model.LoadData();
            view.SetData(data);
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
using System.Linq;

namespace EFCodeFirstMVP
{
    interface IModel
    {
        IQueryable<Goods> LoadData();
    }
}

using System.Linq;

namespace EFCodeFirstMVP
{
    class GoodsModel : IModel
    {
        public IQueryable<Goods> LoadData()
        {
            Context context = new Context();

            var items = from Items in context.Goods
                        select Items;

            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

**Data**

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace EFCodeFirstMVP
{
class Context: DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Goods> Goods { get; set; }
        public DbSet<GoodsList> GoodsList { get; set; }

        public Context()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<Context>());
        }
    }

public class Goods
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        public int Price{ get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ищите в гуголе такие аббревиатуры MVC, MVP, PM, MVVM. MVC самая древняя и простая для понимания.

Comment: Все это хорошо коррелирует с WinForms?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin нет, все это плохо коррелирует с винформс. именно поэтому и придуман WPF.

Comment: На сколько знаю, вполне коррелирует.

Comment: @PashaPash но я хотел бы сначала разобраться с WinForms. Переходить на WPF это поднять еще один пласт и погрузиться в долгие изучения. А WinForms уже кое-как освоен.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin литература по C# лежит [в отдельном вопросе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/). вне его поиск литературы - оффтоп. сам по себе вопрос достаточно обширен, и, если честно, не совсем понятно, что же вы не понимаете. вы не понимаете что такое бизнес логика, чем она отличается от логики UI? или вы не понимаете как ее отделить именно в winforms? :)

Comment: как этого добиться при программировании WinForms

Comment: @banme ну так поделитесь. посылать в гугл все могут.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin не писать код BL в классах форм, выносить его в отдельные классы. это и есть суть разделения.

Comment: @PashaPash нужно прочитать всю эту литературу, чтобы понять или можно как-то сузить круг? Вопрос удалить или можно как-то перефразировать?

Comment: @PashaPash, [например для MVP](http://habrahabr.ru/post/211899/)

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413461/106

Comment: @MikhailDanshin если у вас пример кода, который можно уместить на экран-два - то стоит добавить его в вопрос. если нет, и вы интересуетесь "в целом" - то вас просто пошлют в гугл.

Comment: @PashaPash это был всего лишь комментарий, не претендующий на сколь-нибудь развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: @banme это было посылание в гугл по нескольким ключевым словам :)

Comment: @PashaPash ну ладно. В следующий раз пошлю в яндекс

Comment: @Grundy да, отлично - только по одному паттерну большая объемная статья. прочих вариаций MVx - еще штук 5. это повод закрыть вопрос как "слишком обширный"?

Comment: @andreycha Я читал этот пост. Википедиа прояснила не много. По ссылке на rsdn код с ошибками - не смог с ним разобраться. А на хабре статья не имеет отношения к базам данных. Сложно воспринимать. Это самые лучшие материалы на эту тему?

Comment: @banme а в яндексе первой ссылкой будет этот вопрос на SO :). такое сплошь и рядом в старых вопросах. поддерживаете традиции?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin отделение BL от представления не имеет отношения к базам данных. статья на хабре актуальна, но ее целиком в ответ не скопипастишь.

Comment: @PashaPash, может и стоит :-) но если автор отредактирует вопрос и выберет какой-то один из вариантов - то вполне можно будет дать примерный ответ :-)

Comment: @MikhailDanshin определитесь с конкретным паттерном. но MVVM вам скорее всего посоветуют перейти на WPF. я бы предложил MVP, но с десктопом не работал достаточно давно :(

Comment: Что нужно выбрать? Давайте я выберу. :) Я так понял, что при работе с WinForms лучше подходит MVP. Я тогда выбираю MVP.

Comment: @PashaPash Моя книжка (автор не я, я покупатель) про MVC уже давно пошла коту под хвост в прямом смысле. Остальные знания только в интернете. В гугле, MSDN-е. По мере надобности набрал поиск, навёл справки. Я могу только подсказать тему поиска.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin и ... вопрос закрывают как дубликат http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/ :)

Comment: @MikhailDanshin я повесил конкурс на http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/ - раз уж вы выбрали МVP - ждите ответов там. насчет этого вопроса - не уверен :(

Comment: Вот ещё могу упомянуть такого персонажа - мартин фаулер. Это он всё мутит с паттернами

Comment: @banme они все мутят, но удобство применения каждого паттерна зависит от платформы. что в WPF хорошо - в винформах смерть.

Comment: @banme Я задал этот вопрос когда окончательно запутался со статьей Фаулера по IoC и DI. :)

Comment: @Mikhail _"Все это хорошо коррелирует с WinForms?"_ в WinForms есть bindings, но не такие удобные как в WPF. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474676/196972)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33083/discussion-on-question-by-mikhail-danshin-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Окей, давайте попробуем поговорить об этом вне привязки к WinForms.

Смотрите. У вас есть две различные вещи: внутреннее поведение программы, и то, как она показывает это пользователю. Представьте себе, чтобы вы пишете программное обеспечение радара. У вашей программы внутри есть список отслеживаемых самолётов. Вы принимаете информацию с датчиков, обсчитываете её, принимаете решение о том, возник новый самолёт, или ложная цель, или известный вам самолёт переместился. Всё это происходит внутри, и для этого взаимодействие с пользователем не так уж и обязательно. Это внутренняя часть программы, *модель*.

Теперь, вам нужно донести эту информацию до оператора. В каком виде вы будете *представлять* информацию — в виде распечаток зелёного текста на чёрном фоне, или в виде трёхмерной голографической визуализации — не так уж важно, и модель по существу не зависит от этой части.

Поэтому вы должны писать модель так, чтобы модель ничего не знала о представлении. Это не то, чтобы строго обязательно, но это позволяет разделить программу на независимые части, и даёт лёгкость работы с ними.

Здесь ещё остаются открытыми вопросы о том, как передавать действия пользователя модели, но это отдельная тема.

Посмотрим на более приземлённый пример: работа с базой данных.

Точно так же у вас есть модель: база данных, и операции над ней, которые вы собираетесь делать. Это всё организуется в модуль, возможно, навешивается сверху синхронизация и асинхронность, на этом модель можно считать оконченной.

Представление должно просто

- показывать пользователю часть модели
- принимать у пользователя команды, и доставлять их модели
- после обновления модели показывать обновлённую информацию

Обычно выделяют ещё и промежуточный уровень — бизнес-логику, контроллер, view model, которые занимаются пинанием модели, с тем чтобы представление занималось только представлением.

Comment: модель это не база данных

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy: Аргументируйте? Чем она не модель? С точки зрения трёхзвенной архитектуры — вполне себе модель. Если вы хотите ещё более детального дробления, то может быть, в каких-то классификациях у базы и будет своё отдельное звено, но в рамках данного обсуждения это не важно.

Comment: Вы говорите, что модель не знает о представлении. Какую модель вы имеете ввиду? Ну база и так не слухом не духом о представлении. Если о модели предметной области, то база будет оной наверное только для инструментов типа SSMS. Для остальных база - это хранилище.

Comment: Сейчас перечитал вопрос, и понял, что OP как раз говорит, что проектирует приложение для работы с базами данных, так что винюсь. То есть, как раз таки и проектируется подобное SSMS приложение. Интересно, что же на самом деле имел ввиду OP?

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy: Думаю, чисто практически OP не хочет больше писать код для работы с базой в `OnClick`, и спрашивает о том, а где же надо, и как правильно.

Comment: @VladD А как мне узнать побольше о том, как передавать действия пользователя модели?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: Это зависит от вашего фреймворка. В WPF обычно применяется [`ICommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), как правильно в WinForms, я, к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: @VladD Как считаете, чтобы это узнать - можно задать отдельный вопрос?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: Да! Это важный вопрос.

Comment: _"как передавать действия пользователя модели?"_ -- подписаться на например на событие CurrentItemChanged. его можно получить через BindingContext см. [пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/478617/196972)

Answer (score 1):

Когда говорят, что форма/UI/View отделена от логики/модели, то имеется ввиду, что UI определен в отдельном namespace и/или class.
 
При этом View получает минимальное количество информации о модели. 
View подключается к стандартным интерфейсам модели и таким образом может отслеживать и выводить на экран изменения данных.

Ниже пример, в котором модель отделена от View. По таймеру в модель добавляются  данные, которые выводятся в View.

```
class View {
    static public void Show(object model, string member) {
        // создаем UI
        var f = new Form();
        var g = new DataGridView() { 
                  Parent = f, 
                  Dock = DockStyle.Fill, 
                  DataSource = model, 
                  DataMember = member };
        f.ShowDialog();
    }
}

class Model {
    public Model() {
        // создаем модель - набор данных и правила их обработки  
        var d = new DataSet();
        d.ReadXml(new StringReader("<data><row i='1' /><row i='2' /></data>"));
        // создаем таймер, для изменения модели раз в секунду
        var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
        // обработчик событий таймера 
        timer.Tick += (s, e) => {
            var t = d.Tables["row"];
            // создаем новую строку 
            var r = t.NewRow();
            r[0] = DateTime.Now.Millisecond;
            // доавляем строку в DataSet. при этом UI обновится сам.
            t.Rows.Add(r);
        };
        // запускаем таймер
        timer.Start();
        this.DataMember = "row";
        this.DataSource = d;
    }
    public readonly string DataMember;
    public readonly object DataSource;
}

[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    var m = new Model();
    // создаем UI и привязываем его к модели
    View.Show(m.DataSource, m.DataMember);
}
```

Comment: еще один пример реализации Model и View (использующий WinForms bindings) - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474676/196972)