# Как организовать множественные условия в программе?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Есть форма. На ней много настроек. Для ниспадающего списка `Поворот изображения` есть три варианта - `Нет, Горизонтально, Вертикально`. Есть `numericUpDown` в котором значения от 0 до 100. Если значение равно нулю - то мы его не берем в условие. Дальше описывать элементы думаю смысла нет.

Мне сперва приходится проверить чему равно значение `Поворот изображения`.

```
if (combobox1 = "Нет"){

}
if (combobox1 = "Горизонтально"){

}
if (combobox1 = "Вертикально"){

}
```

И в каждом условии мне приходится еще проверять а не равно ли `numericUpDown` нулю.

```
if (combobox1 = "Нет"){
      if (numericUpDown>0){
}
    }
    if (combobox1 = "Горизонтально"){
      if (numericUpDown>0){
}    
    }
    if (combobox1 = "Вертикально"){
          if (numericUpDown>0){
}
    }
```

Получается индусский код) Думаю для таких решений есть более изящные решения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы бы привели более полный код. Что у вас внутри условий?

Comment: Сам метод ничего не даст, имхо. Тут ведь в организации проблемы

Comment: Для начала, значением, получаемым от комбобокса, должна быть не строка, а enum. Затем, не вижу причины не проверить значение на 0 до начала остальных проверок. В третьих, ваши контролы называются ужасно: `combobox1` и `numericUpDown`. Если вам не жалко себя, уж для нас придумайте осмысленное имя. В-четвёртых, вы бы отделили логику программы от вычитывания значений из UI.

Answer (score 1):

Если надо выполнять проверку введенных значений, то контролы с помощью binding можно привязать к своему объекту с данными (пример для WinForms -- [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474676/196972)), а валидацию значений выполнять с помощью Data Annotations (описание и пример есть в [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd901590(VS.95).aspx) и [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/256183/DataAnnotations-Validation-for-Beginner)).