# Как правильно передавать данные из Model во View через Presenter при использовании EF, CodeFirst, Linq?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, mvp

Я пытаюсь спроектировать приложение реализующее паттерн MVP на WinForms.

При этом я использую EF+CodeFirst+Linq

На **View** есть `DataGridView`, который нужно заполнить данными. **View** вызывает метод `Select()` класса **Presenter**, который в свою очередь вызывает метод `Select()` класса **Model**.

Как правильно предать полученные из БД данные обратно в **Presenter**, чтобы тот вставил их во **View**?

Через возврат значения не получается т.к. используется `using`. Отказываться от `using`?

**Реализация Model.Select()**

```
    internal void Select()
    {
        using (GoodsContext context = new GoodsContext())
        {
            var items = from Items in context.Goods
                        select Items;
        }
    }
```

**UPD:**

Уходить от Linq не вариант.

Comment: в winforms есть binding'и. контролы можно привязать к источнику данных -- см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-mvp-winforms/474676#474676)

Comment: Я так понимаю binding и MVP - это разные подходы.

Comment: вам надо именно mvp или надо правильно (т.е. на основе того, что есть в winforms)?

Comment: @Stack хороший вопрос! :) Вообще я изучаю подход MVP для WinForms. А вы хотите сказать, что MVP - это не правильно при использовании WinForms?

Comment: _"Вообще я изучаю подход MVP"_ -- хорошо, но на практике надо эффективно (с минимальным SLOC) использовать то, что есть. а есть в WinForms возможность создавать привязки между контролами источниками данных. в WPF тоже есть привязки и они удобнее/лучше, чем в WinForms.

Comment: @Stack Ну а как binding в WinForm согласуется с концепцией отделения представления от модели и бизнеслогики? Я так понимаю, что при таком подходе есть прямая жесткая связка между представлением и моделью. Или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: _"жесткая связка между представлением и моделью"_ -- жесткая - это когда у модели невозможно поменять view (с winforms на wpf или web) не меняя код модели.

Comment: @Stack а где в случае с binding+winforms размещается бизнес-логика?

Comment: что такое бизнес-логика в коде? в коде есть классы (созданы на основе сущностей предметной области), есть методы. в них и находится логика. а binding - как мост между объектами (т.е. экземплярами классов) и контролами UI.

Comment: Эээ... А зачем вам select? Ваш код внутри using эквивалентен такому: `var items = context.Goods`.

Comment: @VladD Как я уже сказал, я только учусь. И такие способы приводятся в примерах. Вот [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542) например или [тут](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx). Это неправильные примеры? Как правильно?

Comment: посмотрите [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477796)

Comment: @Stack А на какой мой вопрос это ответ? Что за подход используется в ответе? Где о нем можно почитать из первоисточника?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin _"А на какой мой вопрос это ответ?"_ -- на вопрос "как передать данные во View". первоисточником всего этого является microsoft, почитать можно msdn и/или посмотреть [исходники .net](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/)

Comment: @MikhailDanshin есть определение MVP в википедии и есть его интерпретация [в ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/)  вы какой вариант используете? дополните вопрос, чтобы было понятно.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: Примеры правильные, там же есть ещё и `order by` или `where`. Если его убрать, то весь `select` окажется не нужен.

Comment: _"как binding в WinForm согласуется с концепцией отделения представления от модели и бизнеслогики?"_ -- посмотрите на примере в ответе - [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/478616/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

*Entity:*

```
public class Customer
{

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Customer other = obj as Customer;
        return Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Name.GetHashCode()
            ^ Address.GetHashCode()
            ^ Phone.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(Customer other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return this.Name == other.Name
            && this.Address == other.Address
            && this.Phone == other.Phone;
    }
}
```

//На самом деле для объяснения не было необходимости расписывать поля и переопределять методы, но решил добавить, т.к. многие это не делают, и еще хуже не знают зачем

*Интерфейс репозитория:*

```
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers();

    Customer GetCustomer(int id);

    ...
}
```

*Реализация репозитория*

```
internal class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{ 
    private readonly DbContext dbContext = new DbContext();

    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        return dbContext.Set<Customer>().ToList();
    }

    Customer GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        return dbContext.Set<Customer>().SingleOrDefault(e => e.Id == id)
    }

    ...

}
```

**Presenter**

```
public class CustomerPresenter
{
    private readonly ICustomerView _view;
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _repository;

    public CustomerPresenter(ICustomerView view, ICustomerRepository repository)
    {
        _view = view;
        view.Presenter = this;
        _repository = repository;

        UpdateCustomerListView();
    }

    private void UpdateCustomerListView()
    {
        var customerNames = from customer in _repository.GetAllCustomers() select customer.Name;
        int selectedCustomer = _view.SelectedCustomer >= 0 ? _view.SelectedCustomer : 0;
        _view.CustomerList = customerNames.ToList();
        _view.SelectedCustomer = selectedCustomer;
    }

    public void UpdateCustomerView(int p)
    {
        Customer customer = _repository.GetCustomer(p);
        _view.CustomerName = customer.Name;
        _view.Address = customer.Address;
        _view.Phone = customer.Phone;
    }

    ...
}
```

**View**

*интерфейс вьюхи*

public interface ICustomerView
{
    IList CustomerList { get; set; }

```
int SelectedCustomer { get; set; }

string CustomerName { get; set; }

string Address { get; set; }

string Phone { get; set; }

Presenter.CustomerPresenter Presenter { set; }
```

}

*Реализация интерфейса вьюхи*

```
internal partial class CustomerForm : Form, ICustomerView
{
    private bool _isEditMode = false;

    public CustomerForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IList<string> CustomerList
    {
        get { return (IList<string>)this.customerListBox.DataSource; }
        set { this.customerListBox.DataSource = value; }
    }

    public int SelectedCustomer
    {
        get { return this.customerListBox.SelectedIndex; }
        set { this.customerListBox.SelectedIndex = value; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return this.addressTextBox.Text; }
        set { this.addressTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public string CustomerName
    {
        get { return this.nameTextBox.Text; }
        set { this.nameTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return this.phoneTextBox.Text; }
        set { this.phoneTextBox.Text = value; }
    }

    public Presenter.CustomerPresenter Presenter
    { private get; set; }

    private void customerListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Presenter.UpdateCustomerView(customerListBox.SelectedIndex);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            //логирование ошибки
        }
    }
}
```

PS: В коде могут быть ошибки, т.к. часть кода писал прямо тут, но для объяснения концепции этого должно быть достаточно.