# Как редактировать данные в таблице SQL Server'а с помощью EF CF и WinForms?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, entity-framework

Как с помощью EF Code First можно отредактировать данные в таблице SQL Server'а?
Т.е. надо загрузить данные из таблицы в DataGridView, отредактировать их и сохранить изменения в базе данных.

Answer (score 1):

Например, в SQL Server в базе данных TestDb есть таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](100) NULL
)
```

---

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
class Program {
    class DbContext : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {
        public DbContext()
            : base(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=TestDb;") { }
        public DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; } // или { get { return base.Set<Test>(); } }
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var dc = new DbContext();
        var f = new Form();
        var dg = new DataGridView() { Parent = f, Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        dg.DataSource = // выводим в грид только часть данных из таблицы
            dc.Tests.Where(v => v.Id < 10).ToList();
        f.ShowDialog();
        dc.SaveChanges();  // сохраняем изменения в базе данных
    }
    [Table("Test")]     // без этого EF пытается работать с таблицей Tests
    public class Test {
        [Key] public int Id { get; set; }  // [Key] необходим для работы EF
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Для компиляции кода, к WinForms проекту надо подключить nuget-пакет [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework).