# Как отслеживать изменения в dataGridView и передавать их в Presenter?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

Я использую `WinForms`, `Entity Framework`, `Code First`, `Disconnected Entity`. При этом пытаюсь реализовать паттерн **MVP**.

Есть форма, на ней есть `dataGridView`. Как реализовать сохранение изменений в Базе Данных? Нужно как-то отслеживать изменения в `dataGridView` и предавать их в **Presenter**.

Сейчас на ум не приходит ничего лучшего чем реагировать на событие `CellEndEdit`, конструировать объект и передавать его в контроллер. Но может есть способ изящнее?

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        Goods goods = new Goods();

        goods.GoodsId = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
        goods.Name = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        goods.Price = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value;
        goods.Descriprion = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        goods.Barcode = (int)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value;

        presenterGoods.Update(goods);
}
```

Comment: _"предавать их в Presenter"_ -- в определенни Presenter'а сказано: " извлекает данные из Модели и форматирует их для отображения в Представлении" -- эту функцию в WinForms и WPF выполняет Binding + Convertor'ы. т.е. Binding в своем коде определять не нужно. т.е. берете Модель (например свой объект c реализацией  INotifyPropertyChanged) и Представление (например, TextBox) и связывается binding'ом. При этом свойство объекта может быть Color, а в TextBox будет выводиться #e1e1e1, при изменении строки, значение в binding'е конвертируется в Color и сохраняется в объекте.

Comment: В моем случае Представление ничего не занет о Модели и общается с ней через контроллер. Мне нужно как-то собрать данные, которые были изменены в dataGridView и каким-то образом их передать.

Comment: _"Представление ничего не занет о Модели"_ -- у контролов есть DataSource, т.е. UI ничего специального не знает о модели. _"были изменены в dataGridView и каким-то образом их передать."_ -- через привязку данных изменения автоматически передаются из UI обратно в модель. пример [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/477795).

Answer (score 1):

В WinForms для биндинга коллекций используется `BindingList`

```
var list = new List<Person>()
{
    new Person { Name = "Joe", },
    new Person { Name = "Misha", },
};
var bindingList = new BindingList<Person>(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
grid.DataSource = source;
```

Как минимум изменение `bindingList` должно отображаться в гриде. Обратное по идее тоже, проверяйте.

ПС: если нет принципиальных ограничений, я бы таки не использовал WinForm, который давно не развивается. WPF и то удобнее, хотя полезных плюшек тоже давно нее было.

Comment: Простите, не совсем понял Ваш ответ. Вы привели пример как из коллекции заполнить таблицу. А у меня с заполнением таблицы проблем нет.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin после заполнения коллекция и таблица должны будут сами синхронизировать свои данные.