# Где найти информацию о паттерне Application Controller?

Tags: c#, winforms, шаблоны-проектирования, mvp

Разбираясь с паттерном **MVP** наткнулся на очередной смежный паттерн - **Application Controller**. Но к своему удивлению не смог найти по нему исчерпывающей информации на русском языке, с описанием и примером кода реализации и использвоания. Не подскажете, где мне найти такую информацию?

Или может кто-то возьмется новичку объяснить работу данного паттерна на собственном примере?

**UPD:**
Сейчас важно понять как это устроено и как работает на примере для winforms.

Comment: Может быть, паттерн называется MVC?

Comment: [вот например](http://design-pattern.ru/patterns/application-controller.html)  правда без кода

Comment: @Grundy Это читал. Но там новичку не понять ничего. Нужен пример реализации и использования. Сам же я его не смогу реализовать.

Comment: @VladD Я читал вот [эту статью](http://habrahabr.ru/post/211899/). А там основой всего является Application Controller. Только там не уделяется достаточно внимания для его описания. А разбирать код без описания сложно. Не понять где что и для чего используется. И почему именно так, а не иначе.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: По тексту статьи, это просто экземпляр контроллера, отвечающий за всё приложение. Плюс почему-то он ещё и занимается Dependency Injection'ом (судя по всему, просто некуда было впихнуть).

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: А исходя из статьи, приведённой Grundy, это просто главный контроллер (отвечает за бизнес-логику верхнего уровня).

Comment: @VladD Экземпляр какого контроллера? Как разобраться и понять как это устроено и как работает?

Comment: @VladD На статью, который привел Grundy меня вывела ссылка из статьи, которую привел я. Но не могу во всем этом разобраться без детального описания.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: Ну, контроллер как в MVC. Откуда он взялся вдруг в MVP, вопрос не ко мне. В MVVM до сих пор ведутся споры, является ли бизнес-логика частью VM (то есть, за неё отвечает некий аналог контроллера), или модели (и тогда это просто ещё одна часть модели).

Comment: @VladD Если такому профессионалу как Вы это сходу непонятно, то представьте каково мне - я как Алиса в кроличьей норе. :)

Comment: @VladD Мне бы сейчас отложить в сторонку MVC, MVVM, MVP, со всеми ихними различиями и особенностями и разобраться бы с этим Application Controller-ом.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin, если дружите с английским или хотя бы можете понять смысл переведенного гуглом, то вот вам ссылка с примером https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2009/04/18/decoupling-workflow-and-forms-with-an-application-controller/

Comment: _"наткнулся на очередной смежный паттерн"_ -- он не смежный, а тотже controller. это как с автомобилями. выпустили модель. кто-то ее перекрасил в желтый цвет и называет "такси", кто-то поставил мигалку и называет "патруль". вариантов множество, но автомобиль тотже самый. так и с паттернами, есть MVC  - автомобиль, а все остальное -  производные, в которых что только не придумывают. потому что проще придумать и написать статью, чем разобраться в том, что уже реализовано. а описание app controller есть у Martin Fowler- [тут](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html)

Comment: @MikhailDanshin: Мне кажется, вы подходите как-то не так. Смотрите. У вас в приложении есть несколько заданий, которые нужно выполнить. Отрисовка View. Собственно вычисления. Предоставление данных для View. Получение действий пользователя у View. Переход между состояниями вследствие действий пользователя или изменившегося состояния вычислений. Вот все эти паттеры (MVP, MVC, ...) и строятся вокруг того, какие из этих частей кода видят другие части, и какие управляют какими.

Comment: @VladD С тем о чем Вы сейчас говорите я почти разобрался. Мне только незнакома конструкция Application Controller, которую применил автор статьи из приведенной мною ссылки. Вот я и пытаюсь понять как эта конструкция устроена и как она работает.

Comment: @Dmitry Спасибо за ссылку. В принципе с английским проблем нет. Просто на родном языке все же быстрее и когда тема вообще не знакома, то гораздо проще. Но похоже на русском об этом никто не пишет. Буду читать Вашу ссылку. Спасбо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Controller не является "смежным", это часть Presenter'a в MVP и Сontroller'a в MVC.

Application Controller обеспечивает централизованный контроль, поиск и вызов вьюх и обработки команд. В то время как фронт-контроллер выступает в качестве централизованного пункта доступа и контроллер для входящих запросов, контроллер приложений отвечает за определение и вызов команды, и для выявления и диспетчеризации в представлении. AC используется для централизации поиска и вызова компонентов обработки запросов, таких как команды и views.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Преимущества:

- Улучшает расширяемость
- Улучшает распределение задач

Когда использовать:

- Когда есть необходимость в вынесении логики приложения из
  Presenter/Сontroller
- Есть централизованное управление вьюхами

Comment: Application Controller используют в сложных системах, когда есть несколько контроллеров. И чтобы не было дублирования кода в разных контроллерах, общий код выносят в Application Controller.

Comment: @Stack из [вот этой](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413445/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-mvp-winforms) статьи я понял, что у каждой формы в проекте должен быть свой контроллер/презентер.

Comment: @Stack паттернов которые используются в сложных системах и которые решают проблему дублирования кода - множество. Однако речь идет о архитектурном паттерне. Думаю вы поняли о чем я.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin _"у каждой формы в проекте должен быть свой контроллер/презентер. "_ -- да. и если в них код повторяется, то этот код выносят в Application Controller. но это в теории. на практике Form - это и есть controller / presenter, а View - это системные окна с которыми Form работает через вызовы WinAPI.

Comment: @MikhailDanshin посмотрите ответ [Как перевести понятия MVP в термины WinForms?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/479865)

Comment: @Stack Вот это Вы мне сейчас все шаблоны порвали! :) Как это "View - это системные окна". Ничего не понял. Можете как-то проиллюстрировать то о чем Вы говорите на примере кода?

Comment: @MikhailDanshin _"Вот это Вы мне сейчас все шаблоны порвали! :)"_  -- ну извините :) просто сам мучался долгое время. познал дзен. а т.к.  уже несколько раз видел ваши вопросы, поэтому написал, хотя мне было нелегко, и чувствую минусаторы уже близко :) 
_"Можете как-то проиллюстрировать"_ -- по ссылке есть пример кода на c#. или пример нужен для application controller?

Answer (score -1):

Книга:
Мет Зандстра. PHP: объекты, шаблоны и методики программирования. 398 страница. Все подробно разжевано и указаны различия с Front Controller

Comment: Извините, но ваш ответ, не является ответом. Это скорее комментарий, ссылка на страницу книги, даже не на сайт, который можно оперативно открыть и прочитать. За ответ можно было бы принять хотя бы цитату с описанием собственного понимания.