# Как в Visual Studio связать два элемента формы без кода?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

Как связать элементы формы ?

Например, **ToolStripMenuItem** (пункт меню с галочкой) связать с **ToolStripButton** (кнопка-переключатель панели инструментов) - что бы при изменении свойства **checked** у первого оно менялось и у второго, и наоборот.

Пробовал делать через ApplicationSettings, но связывание не работает.
Кодом писать не хочется, потому что нужно по **checked** изменялась видимость панели, и это состояние сохранялось после перезапуска.
В прошлом году видел статью в интернете как связывать элементы формы без кода. Увы ссылка потерялась. Да и после недели упорных поисков уже начинаю сомневаться, что это вообще можно сделать в Visual Studio 2015 C# приложении Windows Forms, хотя это как-то странно... Такой полезной вещи и нет...

Если кто знает как это делается - подскажите пожалуйста, или поделитесь ссылкой.

Comment: Скорее всего это невозможно. Если я правильно понял, Вы хотите связать логикой два элемента у которых свойсво checked отвечает за разные вещи. У одного за чекбокс, а другого нажата ли кнопка. И не совсем ясно что мешает запрограмировать то что вы хотите?

Comment: Нет, логика одна - отражение одного и тоже логического значения. Т.е. при его изменении одним из элементов второй тут же должен его подхватить. Свойство одноименное, одного и того же типа, и смысл по сути один и тот же (true - кнопка вжата, а у пункта меню галка). Практически здесь два элемента управляют видимостью третьего элемента (панели или строки состояния), при этом их состояние должно быть синхронизировано. И пример реализации такой задача я точно уже встречал в сети, но увы, найти сейчас не могу.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы привязать контролы к свойствам других объектов надо использовать DataBinding.
В наследниках Control есть поддержка DataBinding, а в ToolStripMenuItem - нет, но можно добавить.

```
class BindableToolStripMenuItem : ToolStripMenuItem, IBindableComponent {
    BindingContext bc;
    ControlBindingsCollection db;
    public BindingContext BindingContext {
        get {
            if (bc == null) bc = new BindingContext();
            return bc;
        }
        set { bc = value; }
    }
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings {
        get {
            if (db == null) db = new ControlBindingsCollection(this);
            return db;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Пример привязки ToolStripMenuItem.Visible и ToolStripButton.Checked

```
// #r "System.Windows.Forms"
using System.Windows.Forms;

var frm = new Form();
var ms = new MenuStrip() { Parent = frm };
var mi = new BindableToolStripMenuItem() { Text = "item" };
var mb = new ToolStripButton() { Text = "button", CheckOnClick = true };
ms.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { mb, mi });
mi.DataBindings.Add("Visible", mb, "Checked");   // привязываем Visible к Checked.
frm.ShowDialog();
```

При нажатии ToolStripButton меняется значение Checked и соответственно меняется значение ToolStripMenuItem.Visible.

Привязка работает для любого объекта, если в нем реализован INotifyPropertyChanged.

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged { 
   public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate {};
}
```

Пример [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/474676/196972).

Comment: Наверное воспользуюсь этим, спасибо.    
Жаль конечно, что связывание с ApplicationSettings не заработало - был бы идеальный вариант.

Comment: @t1nk _"связывание с ApplicationSettings не заработало"_ -- к Settings можно привязать. добавил [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/488428/196972)

Answer (score 1):

Если в проект добавить файл Settings1.settings
В нем указать: Checked: bool

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Будет создан файл Settings1.Designer.cs
Привязать ToolStripMenuItem.Visible к Checked можно так

```
var f = new Form();
var ms = new MenuStrip() { Parent = f };
var mi = new BindableToolStripMenuItem() { Text = "item" };
ms.Items.Add(mi);
// привязка Visible к Checked
mi.DataBindings.Add("Visible", Settings1.Default, "Checked");

// для теста: меняем значение Checked и меняется Visible
new Button() { Parent = f, Text = "Test", Location = new Point(100, 100) }
  .Click += (s, e) => 
     Settings1.Default.Checked = !Settings1.Default.Checked;

f.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Верно, состояние подхватывается при запуске приложения. Но если с этим же Settings связать CheckBox, то при манипуляции с его checked (галочкой) не подхватываются другими элементами, без ручного изменения Settings. Неужели нет в C# аналога Action которые можно вешать на элементы? Не нашел даже как кнопки панели ToolStrip привязать к RitchTextBox для копирования вставки (что бы при невозможности копирования или вставки соответствующая кнопка становилась неактивной). Как на этом монстре вообще можно что-то писать без ручного программирования каждого элементарного действия?

Comment: @t1nk _"Неужели нет в C# аналога Action которые можно вешать на элементы?"_ -- есть события, например, чтобы реагировать на checked в CheckBox пишем так: `var c = new CheckBox(); c.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => { /* тут код с реакцией на событие */ };`

Comment: Вот и я про то же... Если Checked меняется по DataBinding, то его менять ни один элемент сам не умеет. Да ещё и каждый элемент нужно описать заново, вместо того что бы назначить один раз описанный Action. Ладно, буду мучиться с тем что есть, спасибо.