# Закрытые формы используя ViewModel

Tags: c#, winforms, mvc, viewmodel

Имеется AppController - где идет управление всеми формами

```
public class AppController : IAppController
{
    private readonly MainForm_MedicalRecord _mainForm;
    public IDataContext DataContext { get; }
    public IMessageService MessageService { get; }

    public AppController(IDataContext dataContext, IMessageService messageService)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dataContext));
        MessageService = messageService ??
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(messageService));

        var vm = new MainViewModel(this);
        _mainForm = new MainForm_MedicalRecord(vm);
    }

    public Form GetMainForm()
    {
        return _mainForm;
    }

    public void ShowCardView()
    {
        var vm = new CardViewModel(this);
        var form = new CardView(vm);
        form.Owner = _mainForm;
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public CardViewModel(AppController appController)
{
    _appController = appController
        ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(appController));
}
```

**CardView**

```
public CardView(CardViewModel cardViewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _viewModel = cardViewModel ??
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cardViewModel));
}
```

Не могу почему то написать метод для закрытия формы. Пытался написать общий метод, но не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста. Ссылался на MVVM, но не подходит так как у меня WindowsForm.

*Дополню... при открытии формы, она дублируется, что мне совсем не нужно.*

> В ShowCardView каждом вызове вы создаете новую форму. Я думаю, что вы хотите вместо этого создать форму один раз и повторно использовать ее. Это означает, что вам нужно сохранить ссылку на него в своем классе AppController в качестве частного поля класса. Тогда вы можете проверить, если он равен нулю. Если это так, создайте один, если он не является нулем, просто покажите его. Если форма может закрываться сама, не забудьте обнулить ссылку в AppController.

... затем, когда у вас есть эта ссылка, вы также должны быть в состоянии к Close нему от AppController.

Comment: Уберите картинки и [вставьте код текстом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109), пожалуйста.

Comment: @aepot Исправил.

Comment: Попробуем разбавить тишину наградой за ответ. :)

Comment: @aepot Спасибо, что привлекаете)

Comment: Дело в том, что здесь полно специалистов по MVVM, в том числе типа я, но только проблема в том, что все применяют его в WPF, так как для WPF это вполне удобный и подходящий шаблон, но никто не заморачивается с этим в Winforms.

Comment: @aepot Да я это прекрасно понимаю, просто кроме метода Show() он ничего не может сделать. И открывает 2ой экземпляр.

Comment: @bulson помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Кстати, вы можете перевести свой вопрос на английский и параллельно запостить на английский SO, там значительно больше народу.

Comment: @aepot цитату одного человека добавил, можете ее перефразировать, или дать какой то пример по его словам?

Comment: Хорошая, понятная цитата, я не знаю как это проще написать.

Comment: [Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/413461/373567) еще что нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private CardView cardView = null;

public void ShowCardView()
{
    if( null == cardView )
    {
        var vm = new CardViewModel(this);
        cardView = new CardView(vm);
        cardView.Owner = _mainForm;
    }
    cardView.Show();
}
```

Правда это не совсем безопасно ! Здесь контроллер будет только создавать новую (отдельную) форму, если ее еще нет. Это позволяет избежать "дублирующихся" форм.

И уже можно добавлять метод Close:

```
public void CloseCardView()
{
     cardView?.Close();
     cardView = null;
}
```

Comment: А что здесь небезопасного? Еще можно вместо `Show()` сделать модальный диалог `ShowDialog(this)`. Тогда пока открыто дочернее окно, главная форма будет недоступна. И закрывать можно будет назначив `DialogResult` кнопкам, И `StartupPosition` `CenterParent` будет работать, но это никак не связано с MVVM. И ловить этот `DialogResult` надо будет внутри `ShowCardView()`, потому что его как раз и возвращает `ShowDialog` при закрытии формы.

Comment: Конкурс закрыл, отдал вам 100 баллов. Можете отметить свой ответ как принятый.